# Nginx by default running on DigitalOcean Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose, port-80, digital-ocean

### Background

So yesterday I was playing around with our server.

On it we have a docker-compose process running 6 or so containers, one of them being Nginx. Before I played around with it yesterday it was serving files just fine.

### What I did

I noticed on DO, that I could upgrade my metrics by running `curl -sSL https://agent.digitalocean.com/install.sh | sh`. How cool right??

Well after I did that, weird stuff started happening. I cant be sure that it is causation, but it certainly is correlation.

### What I tried

I have my DO droplet, and i run `docker-compose up -d` and I get a :

> ERROR: for root_nginx_1  Cannot start service nginx: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint root_nginx_1: Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address already in use

Ok, thats weird...

It was working before and now it wont even start up?

I run `ps aux -P | grep nginx` to see what going on and get:

```
root      1514  0.0  0.1 124972  1388 ?        Ss   12:57   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
www-data  1517  0.0  0.2 125332  2960 ?        S    12:57   0:00 nginx: worker process
root      5716  0.0  0.0  12944   940 pts/1    S+   13:16   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

Hmm, why are there these other nginx processes?

ok, I then run `pkill nginx` to get rid of them and then again `docker-compose up -d` and everything startsup fine and dandy, no errors.

However, now when I go to my `example.com` site, I get no response.

Thinking it might be a config issue, I run `docker logs root_nginx_1` and there is NOTHING. There should be at least some headers or requests being logged.

Then in a desperate final attempt I run `sudo shutdown -r now` and start the whole process over.

Same result with the nginx process running on the server.

So,

1. Is it normal for this nginx process to be running on the server on startup?
2. How can I get my nginx container to listen on port 80 without a conflict?

Comment: This is why curlpipe-style installs are *horrible*. Never, ever use them without first 1) examining the source 2) understanding what exactly it's going to do and 3) testing it out on a test system before your production server.

Comment: Consider my lesson learned.  I trusted DO though...

Comment: There is no way DO nor anyone else can account for every single thing that people might be doing on their servers. It's *your* responsibility, not theirs.

Comment: Is it possible that someone (you?) installed nginx on the machine?

Comment: 1) Ubuntu Docker 17.05.0-ce on 16.04 2) Nope, no one else has access to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After following the advice of @EEAA and actaully researching what the heck DO Agent was doing, it indeed is using port 80 and 443.

> The DigitalOcean Agent uses ports 80 and 443 for outgoing data. Inbound access is not required. Since the Agent only uses the ports for outbound data, you can safely run a web server without interference.
>
> Port 80 is used to contact the DigitalOcean metadata service to obtain
>   an authentication token. The Agent uses this token to authenticate to
>   the metrics backend and encrypt its transmissions.

And after further reading `sudo apt-get purge do-agent` and `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/digitalocean-agent.list` did the trick.

[Here you can](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-the-digitalocean-agent-for-monitoring), and I recommend you do, read all about it.

Comment: This sounds weird, this documentation explicitly states that the problems you experienced should NOT happen?

Comment: Thats what I found strange as well. My thought though is that it had something to do we with issuing `localhost:80` as a port and that had a conflict with the background nginx process.  Where as, in my limited knowledge of nginx, its usually `<ip_address>:80`

Comment: It depends on the vhost configuration what interface / port a specific vhost uses.